# Uneven spacing in footer note with design of a website

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

As a start-up, we are currently developing our website. We have a bit of a programming background, but mainly in Bio-informatics, so HTML and Javascript are unfamiliar. So that's why we will ask this 'stupid' question. We are currently working in WordPress, and we have an issue with the spacing within our Footer Note. There is a dot between the items, but the spacing between these items and dots isn't the same. So it is visually uneven. So the dot has to be there, but the spacing should be even. We have looked at the code, but we can't find this spacing problem. This photo represents the problem, to show it visually.

[image]

Besides that, we use the following code for the Footer

```
    <footer class="footer text-center">
        <div class="container"> 
            <img src="<?= path();?>assets/images/footer-logo.png" alt="" class="footer__logo">
            <p>&copy; <?php echo date('Y');?> Bionomic B.V.</p>
            
            <ul class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => '', 'theme_location' => 'footer', 'items_wrap' => '%3$s') ); ?>    
                <li> <a href="https://www.bionomic.nl/" traget= >Home</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- /* Footer */ -->

    <a href="#" class="scrollup"></a>
</div>
<!-- /* Outer */ -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

<!-- Attched assets/javascripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?= path();?>assets/javascripts/slick.js"></script>
<script src="<?= path();?>assets/javascripts/global.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

If there is anyone who can see the problem in the code, it would be a great help!

Thank you in advance!

Edit: CSS and HTML code for the footer:

```css
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+Chettan+2:wght@400;600;700&family=Open+Sans&display=swap");
@import url("fontawesome/all.css");
/**
 * Set up a decent box model on the root element
 */
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

/**
 * Make all elements from the DOM inherit from the parent box-sizing
 * Since `*` has a specificity of 0, it does not override the `html` value
 * making all elements inheriting from the root box-sizing value
 */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
          box-sizing: inherit;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 32px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 28px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

img {
  border: 0;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  /*Wordpress Image Hack*/
}

img.alignleft {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 0;
}

img.aligncenter {
  margin: 15px auto;
  float: none;
  display: block;
}

img.alignright {
  float: right;
  margin: 15px 0 15px 15px;
}

/**
 * Basic styles for links
 */
a {
  color: #202b59;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #1f2955;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/**
 * Basic typography style for copy text
 */
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #666666;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  body {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Baloo Chettan 2", cursive;
}

/**
 * Clear inner floats
 */
.clear::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/**
 * Main content containers
 * 1. Make the container full-width with a maximum width
 * 2. Center it in the viewport
 * 3. Leave some space on the edges, especially valuable on small screens
 */
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.btn {
  white-space: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 7px 31px 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #202b59;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.btn-primary:after {
  content: '\f105';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.btn-primary.active, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary.active.focus, .btn-primary.active:focus, .btn-primary.active:hover, .btn-primary:active.focus, .btn-primary:active:focus, .btn-primary:active:hover, .btn-primary:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1f2955;
  border-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active {
  background-color: #1f2955;
  border-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-outline-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #fff;
  font-family: "Baloo Chettan 2", cursive;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.btn-outline-primary::before {
  content: '\f061';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  color: #202b59;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.btn-outline-primary--reverse {
  color: #202b59;
  border-color: #0ba3b3;
}

.btn-outline-primary--reverse::before {
  color: #0ba3b3;
}

.btn-outline-primary.active, .btn-outline-primary:active, .btn-outline-primary.focus, .btn-outline-primary:focus, .btn-outline-primary.active.focus, .btn-outline-primary.active:focus, .btn-outline-primary.active:hover, .btn-outline-primary:active.focus, .btn-outline-primary:active:focus, .btn-outline-primary:active:hover, .btn-outline-primary:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #202b59;
  border-color: #202b59;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-outline-primary.active::before, .btn-outline-primary:active::before, .btn-outline-primary.focus::before, .btn-outline-primary:focus::before, .btn-outline-primary.active.focus::before, .btn-outline-primary.active:focus::before, .btn-outline-primary.active:hover::before, .btn-outline-primary:active.focus::before, .btn-outline-primary:active:focus::before, .btn-outline-primary:active:hover::before, .btn-outline-primary:hover::before {
  color: #0ba3b3;
}

.btn-outline-primary:not([disabled]):not(.disabled).active, .btn-outline-primary:not([disabled]):not(.disabled):active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #202b59;
  border-color: #202b59;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-outline-primary:not([disabled]):not(.disabled).active:focus, .btn-outline-primary:not([disabled]):not(.disabled):active:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.form-control {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 24px 0 24px;
}

.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #666666;
}

.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #666666;
}

.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #666666;
}

.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #666666;
}

.form-control:focus {
  border: 1px solid #5cb3fd;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.custom-select {
  background: url("../images/select-arrow.png") right center no-repeat;
  background-size: 24px 40px;
}

.custom-select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.custom-select:focus {
  background: url("../images/select-arrow-down.png") right center no-repeat;
  background-size: 24px 40px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: -4px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #586779;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent;
}

input[type="radio"]::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-image: none;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #586779;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type="radio"]:disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: grey;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: -4px 15px 0 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

input[type="checkbox"]::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-image: none;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #0ba3b3;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  color: #fff;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled {
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

textarea.form-control {
  min-height: 171px;
  padding: 10px 24px 20px 24px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

blockquote {
  margin: 12px 0 12px 20px;
  border-left: 10px solid #ececec;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 70px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

blockquote:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '\201C';
}

blockquote:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: '\201D';
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.wpcf7-form-control-wrap {
  display: block;
}

.wpcf7-form-control-wrap .wpcf7-acceptance .wpcf7-list-item {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.wpcf7-form-control-wrap .wpcf7-checkbox .wpcf7-list-item.first, .wpcf7-form-control-wrap .wpcf7-radio .wpcf7-list-item.first {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.wpcf7-form-control-wrap .wpcf7-not-valid-tip {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.wpcf7-form-control-wrap .wpcf7 form.invalid .wpcf7-response-output,
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap .wpcf7 form.unaccepted
.wpcf7-response-output {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.accHeading {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accHeading .icn:after {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  content: '\f107';
}

.accHeading.collapsed .icn:after {
  content: '\f106';
}

/* Outer */
#outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

/* Tekstblok */
.tekstblok {
  padding-top: 62px;
  padding-bottom: 54px;
}

.tekstblok__img {
  border-radius: 28px 0 28px 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .tekstblok__img {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.tekstblok__txt {
  padding-top: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .tekstblok__txt {
    padding-top: 18px;
  }
}

.tekstblok__txt h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #202b59;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .tekstblok__txt h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
}

.tekstblok__txt p {
  line-height: 1.7;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* Contact */
.contact {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.contact h2 {
  font-size: 34px;
  color: #202b59;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .contact h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 41px;
  }
}

.contact__left {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .contact__left {
    padding-right: 50px;
  }
}

.contact__left p {
  line-height: 1.7;
  margin-bottom: 34px;
}

.contact__left address {
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.contact__left__dtl {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.contact__left__dtl li {
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.contact__left__dtl li a {
  color: inherit;
}

.contact__left__kvk {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 34px;
}

.contact__left__linkedin {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #0ba3b3;
}

.contact__left__linkedin i.fab {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.contact__right {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .contact__right {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.contact__right .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .contact__right .wpcf7-spinner {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}

.contact__right .wpcf7-response-output {
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-width: 1px !important;
}

.contact__right label {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .contact__right label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.contact__right label a {
  color: #0ba3b3;
}

/* footer */
.footer {
  background-color: #202b59;
  padding-top: 41px;
  padding-bottom: 36px;
}

.footer__logo {
  margin-bottom: 51px;
}

.footer p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.footer ul li {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.footer ul li + li::before {
  content: '\f111';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3px;
  color: #0ba3b3;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.footer ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

a.scrollup {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  height: 47px;
  width: 47px;
  line-height: 48px;
  background-color: #202b59;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: -24px;
}

a.scrollup:before {
  content: '\f062';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Slick Slider */
.slick-slider {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-dotted.slick-slider {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.slick-list {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slick-list:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.slick-list.dragging {
  cursor: move;
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.slick-track:before, .slick-track:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.slick-track:after {
  clear: both;
}

.slick-loading .slick-track {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  outline: 0;
  display: none;
}

[dir="rtl"] .slick-slide {
  float: right;
}

.slick-slide.slick-loading img {
  display: none;
}

.slick-slide.dragging img {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
  display: block;
}

.slick-loading .slick-slide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-vertical .slick-slide {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
  display: none;
}

/* Arrows */
.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
          transform: translate(0, -50%);
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slick-prev:hover, .slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

.slick-prev:hover:before, .slick-prev:focus:before,
.slick-next:hover:before,
.slick-next:focus:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slick-prev.slick-disabled:before,
.slick-next.slick-disabled:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: -20px;
}

[dir="rtl"] .slick-prev {
  left: auto;
  right: -25px;
}

.slick-prev:before {
  content: '\f053';
}

[dir="rtl"] .slick-prev:before {
  content: '';
}

.slick-next {
  right: -20px;
}

[dir="rtl"] .slick-next {
  left: -25px;
  right: auto;
}

.slick-next:before {
  content: '\f054';
}

[dir="rtl"] .slick-next:before {
  content: '';
}

.slick-dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-dots li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slick-dots li button {
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slick-dots li button:hover, .slick-dots li button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.slick-dots li button:hover:before, .slick-dots li button:focus:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slick-dots li button:before {
  content: '\f111';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
  color: red;
  opacity: 1;
  content: '\f192';
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=theme.css.map */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-GB" class="no-js">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <!-- Title Tag -->
    <title> bionomic</title>  

    <!-- <<Mobile Viewport Code>> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <meta name='robots' content='noindex, nofollow' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//code.jquery.com' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/13.1.0\/72x72\/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/13.1.0\/svg\/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/mmbeta.nl\/bionomic\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.8.2"}};
            !function(e,a,t){var n,r,o,i=a.createElement("canvas"),p=i.getContext&&i.getContext("2d");function s(e,t){var a=String.fromCharCode;p.clearRect(0,0,i.width,i.height),p.fillText(a.apply(this,e),0,0);e=i.toDataURL();return p.clearRect(0,0,i.width,i.height),p.fillText(a.apply(this,t),0,0),e===i.toDataURL()}function c(e){var t=a.createElement("script");t.src=e,t.defer=t.type="text/javascript",a.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t)}for(o=Array("flag","emoji"),t.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},r=0;r<o.length;r++)t.supports[o[r]]=function(e){if(!p||!p.fillText)return!1;switch(p.textBaseline="top",p.font="600 32px Arial",e){case"flag":return s([127987,65039,8205,9895,65039],[127987,65039,8203,9895,65039])?!1:!s([55356,56826,55356,56819],[55356,56826,8203,55356,56819])&&!s([55356,57332,56128,56423,56128,56418,56128,56421,56128,56430,56128,56423,56128,56447],[55356,57332,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56418,8203,56128,56421,8203,56128,56430,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56447]);case"emoji":return!s([10084,65039,8205,55357,56613],[10084,65039,8203,55357,56613])}return!1}(o[r]),t.supports.everything=t.supports.everything&&t.supports[o[r]],"flag"!==o[r]&&(t.supports.everythingExceptFlag=t.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&t.supports[o[r]]);t.supports.everythingExceptFlag=t.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!t.supports.flag,t.DOMReady=!1,t.readyCallback=function(){t.DOMReady=!0},t.supports.everything||(n=function(){t.readyCallback()},a.addEventListener?(a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",n,!1),e.addEventListener("load",n,!1)):(e.attachEvent("onload",n),a.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===a.readyState&&t.readyCallback()})),(n=t.source||{}).concatemoji?c(n.concatemoji):n.wpemoji&&n.twemoji&&(c(n.twemoji),c(n.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=5.8.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=5.8.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-block-library-css'  href='http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.8.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=5.5.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js?ver=1.5' id='jquery-js'></script>
<link rel="https://api.w.org/" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-json/" /><link rel="alternate" type="application/json" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/2" /><link rel="canonical" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/" />
<link rel='shortlink' href='http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmmbeta.nl%2Fbionomic%2F" />
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmmbeta.nl%2Fbionomic%2F&#038;format=xml" />
<link rel="contents" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic" />
          <link rel="index" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic" />
          <link rel="home" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic" />
            <link rel='archives' title='November 2021' href='http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/2021/11/' />
<style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>
    
    <!-- <<Attched Stylesheets>> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-content/themes/meijermedia/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    
    
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    </head>

<body class="home page-template-default page page-id-2 logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support" >

    <!-- \* Footer *\ -->
    <footer class="footer text-center">
        <div class="container"> 
            <img src="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-content/themes/meijermedia/assets/images/footer-logo.png" alt="" class="footer__logo">
            <p>&copy; 2021 Bionomic B.V.</p>
            
            <ul class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item-first menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50"><a href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/privacy-statement/">Privacy statement</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item-last menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-51"><a href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/algemene-voorwaarden/">Algemene voorwaarden</a></li>
    
                <li> <a href="https://www.bionomic.nl/" traget= >Home</a></li> 
                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- /* Footer */ -->

    <a href="#" class="scrollup"></a>
</div>
        
<!-- Attched assets/javascripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-content/themes/meijermedia/assets/javascripts/slick.js"></script>
<script src="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-content/themes/meijermedia/assets/javascripts/global.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a snippet which contains the minimal HTML, CSS and Javascript code that's necessary to reproduce the issue? You can view the page source of your side in your browser. Thanks!

Comment: post has been edited with the CSS and HTML code for the footer. Javascript isn't needed for that section of the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I change the margin to 7px, it seems that it solves the problem:

```css
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo+Chettan+2:wght@400;600;700&family=Open+Sans&display=swap");
@import url("fontawesome/all.css");
/**
 * Set up a decent box model on the root element
 */
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

/**
 * Make all elements from the DOM inherit from the parent box-sizing
 * Since `*` has a specificity of 0, it does not override the `html` value
 * making all elements inheriting from the root box-sizing value
 */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
          box-sizing: inherit;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 32px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 28px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 20px;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

img {
  border: 0;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  /*Wordpress Image Hack*/
}

img.alignleft {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 0;
}

img.aligncenter {
  margin: 15px auto;
  float: none;
  display: block;
}

img.alignright {
  float: right;
  margin: 15px 0 15px 15px;
}

/**
 * Basic styles for links
 */
a {
  color: #202b59;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
  color: #1f2955;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/**
 * Basic typography style for copy text
 */
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #666666;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #fff;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  body {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  color: #000;
  font-family: "Baloo Chettan 2", cursive;
}

/**
 * Clear inner floats
 */
.clear::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/**
 * Main content containers
 * 1. Make the container full-width with a maximum width
 * 2. Center it in the viewport
 * 3. Leave some space on the edges, especially valuable on small screens
 */
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.btn {
  white-space: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 7px 31px 10px 30px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

.btn-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #202b59;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.btn-primary:after {
  content: '\f105';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.btn-primary.active, .btn-primary:active, .btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary.active.focus, .btn-primary.active:focus, .btn-primary.active:hover, .btn-primary:active.focus, .btn-primary:active:focus, .btn-primary:active:hover, .btn-primary:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #1f2955;
  border-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active {
  background-color: #1f2955;
  border-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-outline-primary {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #fff;
  font-family: "Baloo Chettan 2", cursive;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.btn-outline-primary::before {
  content: '\f061';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  color: #202b59;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-right: 16px;
}

.btn-outline-primary--reverse {
  color: #202b59;
  border-color: #0ba3b3;
}

.btn-outline-primary--reverse::before {
  color: #0ba3b3;
}

.btn-outline-primary.active, .btn-outline-primary:active, .btn-outline-primary.focus, .btn-outline-primary:focus, .btn-outline-primary.active.focus, .btn-outline-primary.active:focus, .btn-outline-primary.active:hover, .btn-outline-primary:active.focus, .btn-outline-primary:active:focus, .btn-outline-primary:active:hover, .btn-outline-primary:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #202b59;
  border-color: #202b59;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-outline-primary.active::before, .btn-outline-primary:active::before, .btn-outline-primary.focus::before, .btn-outline-primary:focus::before, .btn-outline-primary.active.focus::before, .btn-outline-primary.active:focus::before, .btn-outline-primary.active:hover::before, .btn-outline-primary:active.focus::before, .btn-outline-primary:active:focus::before, .btn-outline-primary:active:hover::before, .btn-outline-primary:hover::before {
  color: #0ba3b3;
}

.btn-outline-primary:not([disabled]):not(.disabled).active, .btn-outline-primary:not([disabled]):not(.disabled):active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #202b59;
  border-color: #202b59;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.btn-outline-primary:not([disabled]):not(.disabled).active:focus, .btn-outline-primary:not([disabled]):not(.disabled):active:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.form-control {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: none;
  padding: 0 24px 0 24px;
}

.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #666666;
}

.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #666666;
}

.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #666666;
}

.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #666666;
}

.form-control:focus {
  border: 1px solid #5cb3fd;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
}

.custom-select {
  background: url("../images/select-arrow.png") right center no-repeat;
  background-size: 24px 40px;
}

.custom-select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}

.custom-select:focus {
  background: url("../images/select-arrow-down.png") right center no-repeat;
  background-size: 24px 40px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: -4px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #586779;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent;
}

input[type="radio"]::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-image: none;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #586779;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type="radio"]:disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: grey;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  outline: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: -4px 15px 0 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
}

input[type="checkbox"]::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-image: none;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #0ba3b3;
  border-radius: 100px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  color: #fff;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled {
  background-color: grey;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

textarea.form-control {
  min-height: 171px;
  padding: 10px 24px 20px 24px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

blockquote {
  margin: 12px 0 12px 20px;
  border-left: 10px solid #ececec;
  position: relative;
  padding: 30px 70px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

blockquote:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '\201C';
}

blockquote:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  content: '\201D';
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 80px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.wpcf7-form-control-wrap {
  display: block;
}

.wpcf7-form-control-wrap .wpcf7-acceptance .wpcf7-list-item {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.wpcf7-form-control-wrap .wpcf7-checkbox .wpcf7-list-item.first, .wpcf7-form-control-wrap .wpcf7-radio .wpcf7-list-item.first {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.wpcf7-form-control-wrap .wpcf7-not-valid-tip {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.wpcf7-form-control-wrap .wpcf7 form.invalid .wpcf7-response-output,
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap .wpcf7 form.unaccepted
.wpcf7-response-output {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.accHeading {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accHeading .icn:after {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  content: '\f107';
}

.accHeading.collapsed .icn:after {
  content: '\f106';
}

/* Outer */
#outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

/* Tekstblok */
.tekstblok {
  padding-top: 62px;
  padding-bottom: 54px;
}

.tekstblok__img {
  border-radius: 28px 0 28px 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .tekstblok__img {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.tekstblok__txt {
  padding-top: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .tekstblok__txt {
    padding-top: 18px;
  }
}

.tekstblok__txt h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #202b59;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .tekstblok__txt h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
}

.tekstblok__txt p {
  line-height: 1.7;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* Contact */
.contact {
  padding-top: 60px;
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.contact h2 {
  font-size: 34px;
  color: #202b59;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .contact h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 41px;
  }
}

.contact__left {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .contact__left {
    padding-right: 50px;
  }
}

.contact__left p {
  line-height: 1.7;
  margin-bottom: 34px;
}

.contact__left address {
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.contact__left__dtl {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.contact__left__dtl li {
  line-height: 1.7;
}

.contact__left__dtl li a {
  color: inherit;
}

.contact__left__kvk {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 34px;
}

.contact__left__linkedin {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #0ba3b3;
}

.contact__left__linkedin i.fab {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

.contact__right {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .contact__right {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.contact__right .form-group {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .contact__right .wpcf7-spinner {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}

.contact__right .wpcf7-response-output {
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-width: 1px !important;
}

.contact__right label {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .contact__right label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

.contact__right label a {
  color: #0ba3b3;
}

/* footer */
.footer {
  background-color: #202b59;
  padding-top: 41px;
  padding-bottom: 36px;
}

.footer__logo {
  margin-bottom: 51px;
}

.footer p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.footer ul li {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.footer ul li + li::before {
  content: '\f111';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3px;
  color: #0ba3b3;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.footer ul li a {
  color: #fff;
}

a.scrollup {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 20px;
  height: 47px;
  width: 47px;
  line-height: 48px;
  background-color: #202b59;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: -24px;
}

a.scrollup:before {
  content: '\f062';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Slick Slider */
.slick-slider {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
  touch-action: pan-y;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-dotted.slick-slider {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.slick-list {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slick-list:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.slick-list.dragging {
  cursor: move;
  cursor: grab;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.slick-track:before, .slick-track:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}

.slick-track:after {
  clear: both;
}

.slick-loading .slick-track {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  outline: 0;
  display: none;
}

[dir="rtl"] .slick-slide {
  float: right;
}

.slick-slide.slick-loading img {
  display: none;
}

.slick-slide.dragging img {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
  display: block;
}

.slick-loading .slick-slide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-vertical .slick-slide {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
  display: none;
}

/* Arrows */
.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
          transform: translate(0, -50%);
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slick-prev:hover, .slick-prev:focus,
.slick-next:hover,
.slick-next:focus {
  outline: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

.slick-prev:hover:before, .slick-prev:focus:before,
.slick-next:hover:before,
.slick-next:focus:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slick-prev.slick-disabled:before,
.slick-next.slick-disabled:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slick-prev:before,
.slick-next:before {
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.slick-prev {
  left: -20px;
}

[dir="rtl"] .slick-prev {
  left: auto;
  right: -25px;
}

.slick-prev:before {
  content: '\f053';
}

[dir="rtl"] .slick-prev:before {
  content: '';
}

.slick-next {
  right: -20px;
}

[dir="rtl"] .slick-next {
  left: -25px;
  right: auto;
}

.slick-next:before {
  content: '\f054';
}

[dir="rtl"] .slick-next:before {
  content: '';
}

.slick-dots {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -25px;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-dots li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slick-dots li button {
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slick-dots li button:hover, .slick-dots li button:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.slick-dots li button:hover:before, .slick-dots li button:focus:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slick-dots li button:before {
  content: '\f111';
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Pro';
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
  color: red;
  opacity: 1;
  content: '\f192';
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=theme.css.map */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-GB" class="no-js">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <!-- Title Tag -->
    <title> bionomic</title>  

    <!-- <<Mobile Viewport Code>> -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <meta name='robots' content='noindex, nofollow' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//code.jquery.com' />
<link rel='dns-prefetch' href='//s.w.org' />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window._wpemojiSettings = {"baseUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/13.1.0\/72x72\/","ext":".png","svgUrl":"https:\/\/s.w.org\/images\/core\/emoji\/13.1.0\/svg\/","svgExt":".svg","source":{"concatemoji":"http:\/\/mmbeta.nl\/bionomic\/wp-includes\/js\/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=5.8.2"}};
            !function(e,a,t){var n,r,o,i=a.createElement("canvas"),p=i.getContext&&i.getContext("2d");function s(e,t){var a=String.fromCharCode;p.clearRect(0,0,i.width,i.height),p.fillText(a.apply(this,e),0,0);e=i.toDataURL();return p.clearRect(0,0,i.width,i.height),p.fillText(a.apply(this,t),0,0),e===i.toDataURL()}function c(e){var t=a.createElement("script");t.src=e,t.defer=t.type="text/javascript",a.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t)}for(o=Array("flag","emoji"),t.supports={everything:!0,everythingExceptFlag:!0},r=0;r<o.length;r++)t.supports[o[r]]=function(e){if(!p||!p.fillText)return!1;switch(p.textBaseline="top",p.font="600 32px Arial",e){case"flag":return s([127987,65039,8205,9895,65039],[127987,65039,8203,9895,65039])?!1:!s([55356,56826,55356,56819],[55356,56826,8203,55356,56819])&&!s([55356,57332,56128,56423,56128,56418,56128,56421,56128,56430,56128,56423,56128,56447],[55356,57332,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56418,8203,56128,56421,8203,56128,56430,8203,56128,56423,8203,56128,56447]);case"emoji":return!s([10084,65039,8205,55357,56613],[10084,65039,8203,55357,56613])}return!1}(o[r]),t.supports.everything=t.supports.everything&&t.supports[o[r]],"flag"!==o[r]&&(t.supports.everythingExceptFlag=t.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&t.supports[o[r]]);t.supports.everythingExceptFlag=t.supports.everythingExceptFlag&&!t.supports.flag,t.DOMReady=!1,t.readyCallback=function(){t.DOMReady=!0},t.supports.everything||(n=function(){t.readyCallback()},a.addEventListener?(a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",n,!1),e.addEventListener("load",n,!1)):(e.attachEvent("onload",n),a.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",function(){"complete"===a.readyState&&t.readyCallback()})),(n=t.source||{}).concatemoji?c(n.concatemoji):n.wpemoji&&n.twemoji&&(c(n.twemoji),c(n.wpemoji)))}(window,document,window._wpemojiSettings);
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
</style>
    <link rel='stylesheet' id='dashicons-css'  href='http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=5.8.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=5.8.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='wp-block-library-css'  href='http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.8.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=5.5.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js?ver=1.5' id='jquery-js'></script>
<link rel="https://api.w.org/" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-json/" /><link rel="alternate" type="application/json" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/2" /><link rel="canonical" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/" />
<link rel='shortlink' href='http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/json+oembed" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmmbeta.nl%2Fbionomic%2F" />
<link rel="alternate" type="text/xml+oembed" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-json/oembed/1.0/embed?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmmbeta.nl%2Fbionomic%2F&#038;format=xml" />
<link rel="contents" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic" />
          <link rel="index" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic" />
          <link rel="home" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic" />
            <link rel='archives' title='November 2021' href='http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/2021/11/' />
<style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 32px !important; }
    @media screen and ( max-width: 782px ) {
        html { margin-top: 46px !important; }
        * html body { margin-top: 46px !important; }
    }
</style>
    
    <!-- <<Attched Stylesheets>> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-content/themes/meijermedia/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    
    
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    </head>

<body class="home page-template-default page page-id-2 logged-in admin-bar no-customize-support" >

    <!-- \* Footer *\ -->
    <footer class="footer text-center">
        <div class="container"> 
            <img src="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-content/themes/meijermedia/assets/images/footer-logo.png" alt="" class="footer__logo">
            <p>&copy; 2021 Bionomic B.V.</p>
            
            <ul class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <li id="menu-item-50" class="menu-item-first menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50"><a href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/privacy-statement/">Privacy statement</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item-last menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-51"><a href="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/algemene-voorwaarden/">Algemene voorwaarden</a></li>
    
                <li> <a href="https://www.bionomic.nl/" traget= >Home</a></li> 
                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- /* Footer */ -->

    <a href="#" class="scrollup"></a>
</div>
        
<!-- Attched assets/javascripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-content/themes/meijermedia/assets/javascripts/slick.js"></script>
<script src="http://mmbeta.nl/bionomic/wp-content/themes/meijermedia/assets/javascripts/global.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the dot is a regular type of dot seen at the beginning of a HTML list items. You are using an Unordered List `<ul>` and this has individal Lines `<li>` within it. At the beginning of those lines will be a dot unless you dicate otherwise.

If... the list is set up to appear `in-line` then I do think it would appear that the dots are between your menu items.

Try this in your CSS. It will affect all lists on your website.

```
<!-- In your CSS -->

ul {
  list-style:none;
}
```

Or, to affect only that one list. Add a Class to it.

```
<!-- In your CSS -->

ul.no-dots{
  list-style:none;
}

<!-- Then in your HTML -->

 <ul class="no-dots d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center">
```

Comment: I gave it a try, but setting ```<ul>``` to ```in-line``` only dots will appear then. So It does something, but not the right thing.

Comment: `in-line` was only to indicate that in-line lists might make the dots appear between the list items as they are side by side rather than each list item on a new line. So I suspect your list is already in-line. Try `list-style:none;` in your CSS as above to remove the dots.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. The spacing between the dots stays uneven. We would like to keep the dots, but make the spacing even.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help Aanhaai. I was trying to get rid of the dots for you. Could you add a screenshot to your original question as it might help somebody else.

Comment: No problem Cute Code Rob, I really appreciate the try. There is a screenshot within the post which shows the issue visually. It is under a hyperlink by the word Photo.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the dot before your footer links please use the CSS code.

```
footer ul {
list-style:none;
}
```